# PHP fetch_array() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I currently have this PHP code.

```
if (isset($User)){
            if (is_object($User)) {
                if (!$result_paycon = $mysqli->query("CALL CHECK_CONVENTION(" . $User->id . "," . $row_convention["IDCONVENTION"] . ")")){
                    printf("Database error");
                    exit; 
                }

                if (!$result_block = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM VIEW_ROOMBLOCK WHERE IDCONVENTION = " . $row_convention["IDCONVENTION"])){
                    var_dump($result_block);
                    printf("Database error");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
```

No matter what I do with it, the var dump of $result block is always bool(false). And then when I need to use fetch_array on it, it just tells me that $result_block is a non-object. However, changing my first query from a procedure call to a regular select seems to fix the issue, so does removing it entirely from the code.

I echoed the SQL query for both calls, and they both return something if I plug them into SQL directly.

Is there something I'm not doing?

EDIT 1: Still having no luck. However, if I invert the code like this:

```
if (!$result_block = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM VIEW_ROOMBLOCK WHERE IDCONVENTION = " . $row_convention["IDCONVENTION"])){
                    printf("Database error");
                    exit;
                }

                if (!$result_paycon = $mysqli->query("CALL CHECK_CONVENTION(" . $User->id . "," . $row_convention["IDCONVENTION"] . ")")){
                    printf("Database error");
                    exit; 
                }

                var_dump($result_block);
                echo "<br />";
                var_dump($result_paycon);
```

I get the following from the var dumps:

```
object(mysqli_result)#4 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(10) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["type"]=> int(0) }
object(mysqli_result)#5 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(2) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

But with the former code, one of them just fails, I still have no idea why.

EDIT 2: I just printed the value of the error property of the mysqli object in the former code. I get the following:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: It looks like you're only doing `var_dump($result_block);` if the query fails.

Comment: Yes, because this is where I head every single time without fail. The query always fails if I do this first query that calls a procedure. If I replace the procedure by a regular select, that second query works fine.

Comment: Ah okay. I see what you mean. Thanks. Does the first query always fail with `CHECK_CONVENTION`? It looks like the script exits if the first query fails, so the second query will not be performed.

Comment: In a nutshell, I need to run the fetch_array method on the second result object. Issue is, $mysqli->query just fails and I don't obtain an object. Hence why I get into the if in the first place.

Comment: The first query never fails. It currently gives me one record containing two columns. The first column contains "11" and the second "0". I always exit with a dump of $result_block.

Comment: Have you tried to execute second statement in something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Of course, gotcha. Maybe you can get more info regarding the error by outputting `$mysqli->error`.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld, yes I have. I executed the second statement through the database console as well as MySQL Workbench (My Apache server is on a Linux VM).

Comment: @showdev Ran it. I get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. I need to run the next_result() method to prepare the $mysqli object for another query/result set. As implied earlier in the comments in the mysql documentation, free_result should work. But for some reason, it doesn't for me.

So this works:

```
if (isset($User)){
            if (is_object($User)) {
                if (!$result_paycon = $mysqli->query("CALL CHECK_CONVENTION(" . $User->id . "," . $row_convention["IDCONVENTION"] . ")")){
                    printf("Database error");
                    exit; 
                }
                $result_paycon->close();
                $mysqli->next_result();

                if (!$result_block = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM VIEW_ROOMBLOCK WHERE IDCONVENTION = " . $row_convention["IDCONVENTION"])){
                    var_dump($result_block);
                    printf("Database error");
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
```